# How to handle Decimal Separator from xml File?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I receive an `.xml` file from a client and I use the file as a lookup table for my Calculations. I read the `.xml` into a `DataTable`. Below is the code.

```
public static DataSet readXML (string xmlFileName)
{
    try
    {
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        dataSet.ReadXml(xmlFileName);
        return dataSet;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return null; 
    }  
}
```

The issue i face is when I convert the cells from this table to Integer. The error message "Value was either to large or too small for `Int32`. I did debugging and found that the .xml file uses "." decimal separator. My system default decimal separator is ",". I want to make sure when ever I read an .xml file in a DataTable, it always gets a "," separated number. Please guide me.

Comment: The xml file should have a schema. Try dataSet.ReadXml(xmlFileName, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema); If the xml file have an inline schema definition, the elements that contain the decimal values will be inserted into a decimal type column in your data table.

Comment: Have your client save xml with ds.WriteXml("filename", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);

Comment: @jdweng No. It uses  ds.WriteXml("filename"). I know it for sure.

Comment: Then the code becomes much more complicated.  You have to manually parse the xml or use regex to replace all the periods with commas.

Comment: I am putting a little hack as an answer since putting code in comments is no use. Please do not mark as answer.

Comment: Another thing. You will get an error anyways if you try to convert, say, the string "12,56" to integer. You should convert it to decimal.

Comment: You are having the old excel issues with dates.  The dates should be saved as international date format which will work in any country.  Because you don't have a schema, the ReadXml method has to guess the field types and is guessing wrong.  You client is probably saving the DateTime field as a string.  The ReadXml doesn't know it was saved as string and trying to parse a date with default datetime format (usingg county setting on the PC).

Comment: Doesn't look like it; for instance [`DoubleStorage`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/Common/DoubleStorage.cs) just does `XmlConvert.ToDouble(s);` and ignores `DataSet.Locale`.  I suggest preprocessing your XML.  What does it look like?

Comment: @OguzOzgul Why will I get an error if Convert 12,56 to int. I do int integerVal = (int) (Convert.ToDouble("12,56")); I have done all the way like this.

Comment: I meant, Convert.ToInt32("12.56") would fail.. You never mentioned that you first convert it to double and then cast it to int

Comment: I am aware of that failure, sorry I did not mention before. But the error I got was to do with overflow. So that was ruled out anyway.